# Need help Filling UK visa application

Tags: visas, uk

[image]

I am filling the UK visa a0plication just now and I need help. I filled these fields like this. Is it OK?

I am going to apply for a UK visa along with my wife. I will travel with my wife. I will take care of all expenses of our trip. Then is it OK if I fill these fields in my wife application?

Comment: surely you will put how much you will be paying to your wife in the 'How much money will they be paying towards your visit?' field

Comment: I will travel with my wife. I will spend all expense during our trip. In that case, should add amount in wife application?

Comment: If this is YOUR WIFE'S application then she will need to fill out the section "How much money will they be paying towards your visit?" field with an appropriate amount. 0.01 PKR is not enough for any type of proposed visit.